# Is it possible to mirroring specific topics in kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka

Is there anyone knowing how to config Kafka MirrorMaker to mirror some specific topics from source cluster? We have many topics in our source cluster, but we do not mirror all of them. Is it possible? How should we do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use either whitelist or blacklist to specify what topics to mirror. They are just regular expressions - whitelist means mirror everything that matches, blacklist means mirror everything except what matches. You may read more information [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=27846330#Kafkamirroring(MirrorMaker)-Whitelistorblacklist)

Comment: Thank your man. Would you please write an example regular expression for me? Suppose that I want to mirror only topic _first_ to destination server. Is this enough to put topic name in quotes like "first"?

Comment: If you want to match exact string (in your case *first*) then your regex would look like `^first$`